# How can i loose space between words and not loose between phrases

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string that i am trying to reduce the continuous characters in between the string as i still want to convert it back to a list in the future but i get to loose all the spaces in between some words

i am new to the python programming language. I have tried to use the join function but i loose all my spaces

```py
text = 'waiting / / wave / crest / / / wavelength services / / despite / / / / product / '

new_text = ''.join([i for i in new.replace(" ", "").split('') if i])

print(new_text)
```

I want

```
"waiting/wave/crest/wavelength services/despite/product"
```

But I'm getting

```
"waiting/wave/crest/wavelengthservices/despite/product"
```

Comment: instead of getting this 'waiting*wavecrest*wavelength* services*despite*product'

I am getting this 'waiting*wavecrest*wavelengthservices*despite*product'

Comment: There should be a space in between phrases while words have no space. i.e. a phrase is information retrieval while word is information.

Comment: Asterisks were used to replace stopwords

Comment: It should be clearer now... Thank you

Comment: yes it is much clearer now, thanks.

Comment: ```'/'.join(text.split())``` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is a not so simple to understand solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'waiting  wave                 crest       wavelength services  despite   product  '
>>> '/'.join(re.sub(r'(\w)(\s{1})(\w)', r'\1_\3', text).split()).replace('_',' ')
'waiting/wave/crest/wavelength services/despite/product'
>>>
```

What it does is first replace a single space between two words with an underscore, then it splits the sentence, then join them separated by a slash, and finally replace the underscore with a space back.

EDIT: Quoting Raymond Hettinger: "There must be an easier way"...

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'waiting  wave                 crest       wavelength services  despite   product  '
>>> re.sub(r'\s{2,}', '/', text.strip())
'waiting/wave/crest/wavelength services/despite/product'
```

With this last one, `strip()` removes trailing spaces from the beginning and the end of `text` and `re.sub()` replaces every occurrence of 2 or more spaces with a slash.

Comment: Thank you but i want the space to be retained for example "wavelength services" should still be "wavelength services as far as there is no * in between the words wavelength and services

Comment: How do you differentiate that from the other words? What is the rule?

Comment: Assuming as input text i have "* James * * * John Wick * * peter * * * * " i want my output to be *James*John Wick*peter*   if you notice the first one has several * with spaces while output has no space except John wick which was retained and the * reduced to one

Comment: Still not clear to me. Are you saying that if two words are separated by just ONE space them they must stay together?

Comment: Yes they must stay together as one if two words are separated by a space

Comment: @DoubleT, I'm glad to help. If possible, mark my answer as accepted. That will help me as well.